# Posting BitmapImage to Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send a class that contains a BitmapImage to a Web API.

At the moment, when I get to the line below, it simply just waits forever... and I assume will timeout eventually.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", img);
```

The object that 'img' represents looks like this;

```
    public class ImageContainer {
        public BitmapImage TheImage { get; set; }
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
    }
```

It works when I replace 'img' with a simple object, so I can only assume it is having trouble with the BitmapImage?  There is no error that is returned... it just waits.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only single complex type with PostAsJsonAsync. Look at this http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/F2aL081113-Passing-multiple-complex-type-parameters-to-ASP.NET-Web-API.html